# QGIS problems getting layers to line up correctly.

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, vector

I am trying to add a raster layer and a vector layer to qgis.  I have set both of their CSR to NAD83 Oklahoma North State Plane.  It doesn't seem to work even with all the files set to those CSR.   What is likely the issue is that the raster has no extent, and QGIS doesn't seem to have a way to set the extent on rasters.  Coming from ArcGIS world where all these are set on the fly... Where else might I be going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you have set the CRS not correctly. `Set CRS for Layer` is NOT the right method, as it will not reproject the coordinates as you wish. Normally you don't jave to regard the different CRS, when you have `On-the-fly-reprojection` enabled.

Please rightclick on each layer -> Properties, Metadata tab.

There you can read what extent the layers have in their native CRS. If it is between +/- 189/90°, the CRS is in degrees. EPSG:4269 would be suitable for that.